# AFrame Particle System with Custom Particle Positions

Tags: three.js, aframe, webvr

My goal is to use AFrame to create a particle system with a JSON file that contains the x,y and z positions for each particle.

I am aware of IdeaSpace VR's [aframe-particle-system-component](https://github.com/IdeaSpaceVR/aframe-particle-system-component), but not  sure about how to set custom positions for each particle within it.

I am also open to writing a new AFrame component from an existing three.js one if that is necessary. If that is the case, I would hope you could start me off with some code (rather then just suggesting a three JS component)!

Thank you in advance!

[a link](http://www.example.com/)

Comment: Might have to create a new component. Ideaspace's component uses https://github.com/IdeaSpaceVR/aframe-particle-system-component/blob/master/lib/SPE.js which I am not sure lets you set positions individually, it looks like it does everything for you (position, distribution, acceleration, etc.,)

Comment: Thank you ngokevin! Do you know if I can I import a Three JS file like this one - (http://pwambach.github.io/threejs-particle-shader/example-3.html) then create an AFrame component that works with it?

Comment: Yup, you definitely can. Here's the current guide https://aframe.io/docs/0.4.0/core/component.html ... I'm in process of re-writing/reorganizing it + more tutorials on writing a component, but that should get you through the process roughly.

Comment: Okay, I will work on it and post an answer here! And thank you! Big fan of your work!! I'm using AFrame as an intern at NASA-JPL to build VR prototypes for science research. Definitely could not do it without AFrame!!

Comment: Oh, my former roommate interned at NASA-JPL. Awesome, please let me see what you build!